# pop() function is changing multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following click handler, when it is clicked I pull in an array from [handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) and then remove the last element from the array, and pass the new array to an ajax post. the issue is that if I click the button again it removes another item from the array. It seems like the `data` `var` is not being reset to all of the data on click?

```
$('#view-options').on('click', '#act_add', function() {

     var newData = $('#spreadsheet').handsontable("getData");
     var data = newData;
     newData.pop();
     console.log(newData);
     console.log(data);

     $.ajax({
        url: path + "api/v1/apps/add",
        data: {"data": newData},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(res) {
           alertify.success("your data was added to the db");
        }
     });
  });
```

in the previous code `newData` and `data` both log the same array, this does not makes sense considering I only `pop()` the `newData` array

Comment: You assign 'newData' to 'Data', since that moment, both are the same object.

Comment: I am not doing the pop until after, wouldn't this mean that when i  log them they will be different?

Comment: Yeah, when you say `var data = newData;`, you're making data point to the same block of memory as newData, so when you make a change to that memory block, both will be affected. If you only want to affect one, you'd have to copy newData into data, not point data to newData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did this:

```
var data = newData;
```

You set the pointer. So when you modify `newData`, `data` is modified too.

Use [`slice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) function:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var newData = data.slice();
newData.pop();
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Now you copied array (not created the pointer). So there are 2 different arrays, you can't change one of them and another array wouldn't be changed.

Comment: this works, but for some reason each click still pops another item off the end. if I click enough they will be empty. I dont see how this is happening? I am resetting `newData` back to a full array on each click

Comment: nevermind I was popping the wrong var, will mark this as a correct answer!

Comment: @arrowil12 ye.  It was easy mistake, as I thought

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a variable an object it assigns a reference to that object. So in this case newData and data point to the same object. Meaning any changes to data will necessarily change newData. You will have to make a copy of that object for what you're probably trying to achieve.

You can use this line instead of the assignment to copy the contents of the object:

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're copying a javascript Object, so data receives a reference of the object newData.
If you modify one of them, you'll modify the other.

there are sevral ways to copy a JSON object.
the JSON.parse(JSON.strinify(newData)) trick is a solution but not very efficient and inner functions might not work properly after copy.

you'll find very good answers on how to copy these objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).